# Upload java chat server

Tags: google-app-engine, client, chat, java-server

recently I have build a chat application with a client and a server it works fine on a virtual machine. But now I am stuck what I need to do with the server application?
Where can I upload it?

I had found that I can upload apps to Google(app engine) but I don't know the address of the server so the client can't connect to it...
please help me I hope my question is clear...

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine is a PaaS and cannot run any Java Server application that you have written.

So, you will have to make sure that you understand the App Engine platform and write applications using various services that are provided as part of the platform.

To get started, check the following: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction

Google also has an offering called [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine/), that provides you with Linux VMs hosted on the Google infrastructure.

So if you are looking at VMs, where you want to host your application, you could look at that. You definitely have more flexbility with the Compute Engine but you have to deal with configuration, settings things up and more Administrative stuff.

Compute Engine is not free whereas App Engine comes with a generous free quota.

Comment: Thanks, what is easiest way to upload my server application? Right now its running on my comp and i need to leave it turned on in order to use the app... may be some other sites(not google) will help me. For example i know a lot of sites that offer site hosting for free...

Comment: It is too general to answer which other Java hosting solution can run your application. I gave you the pointers vis-a-vis Google Compute Engine and Google App Engine. I believe that given the fact that you might want to run your application as is, it does seem that going with a solution that gives you raw machines might be the way forward for you.